# How can I get a reference of a view from a inflated layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, layout-inflater

I have a huge layout for my activity that i set using `setContentView()`. In that layout I have a `TableLayout`(named `tableLayout` in my Activity) that I want to populate. The rows of that TableLayout are customViews in a layout file(let's call that file `tablerow_layout.xml`). Inside this layout i have some TextViews and ImageView. What I want to do is change the content of the TextView programatically, when I create the row. This is my code:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View newRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow_layout, null, false);
TextView name = (TextView) newRow. findViewById(R.id.tablerow_name);
name.setText("THIS LINE");
tableLayout.addView(newRow);
```

Unfortunately my app crashes when I try to change the content of the TextView. I know that I could do this using a ListView, but I usually have a small number of rows and the overhead of creating another Adapter for the ListView is preatty big.

As @ρяσѕρєя K suggested I also tried newRow.findViewById(...) instead of findViewById(...) without any difference

Answer (score 4):

You are missing to set `newRow`  in your **Textview** .

```
  View newRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow_layout, null, false);
  TextView name = (TextView)newRow.findViewById(R.id.tablerow_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get a reference of a view from a inflated layout

Use `View` object which is returned from `LayoutInflater.inflate` method  to access views from layout which is passed as first parameter to `inflate` method.

In your case, use `newRow` object for accessing views from  `R.layout.tablerow_layout` layout:

```
TextView name = (TextView)newRow.findViewById(R.id.tablerow_name);
```

Comment: Tried this before and doesn't make a difference. Going to edit my question

Answer (score 3):

```
  try

   {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)   
   getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     View newRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow_layout, null,   false);
     TextView name = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.tablerow_name);

     name.setText("THIS LINE");

    tableLayout.addView(newRow);

    }catch(Exception e)

    {

    e.printTracktrace();

    }
```

Comment: It's just going to stop my app from crashing, without setting the actual text.

Answer (score 2):

Using IntelliJ Amiya's and ρяσѕρєя K's answers it worked for me with this code.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = 
(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.profileView);
    ViewGroup viewGroup = linearLayout;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PROFILES; i++){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_badge_layout, viewGroup, false);
        linearLayout.addView(layout);

        TextView names = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        ImageView images = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        names.setText(""+i);


        viewGroup = layout;
    }
```

Each text had it's own i value. I believe you need to add the view first. Then you can change the values